# text-shadow not rendered in print from browser

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

I'm trying to print to .pdf an html page with a text and a text-shadow property, howerver the text shadow does not appear in the pdf preview. This both on Chrome and Firefox. Is there any way to add text and box shadows to the pdf print?

CSS

```
#step p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'IM Fell English', serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-shadow:
    2px 2px 0px #000,
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

Tried opacity:

```
html {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
}
```

tried blur

```
html {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}
```